# Email sent from WordPress has HTML tags

Tags: email, formatting, wp-mail

Instead of:

```
Hello,

Thank you dfasdfasdfasdf asdf asdf asdfas dfs

Please, feelasdf asdf asdf
```

The email that arrives in my mailbox looks like the following:

```
<p>Hello,</p> 
<p>&nbsp;</p> 
<p>Thank you dfasdfasdfasdf asdf asdf asdfas dfs</p> 
<p>&nbsp;</p> 
<p>Please, feel asdfads fad f</p>
```

So, I guess the HTML is not turned on for the `wp_mail()` function? How do you turn it on so the mail will arrive as it should and the `<p>` and `<br>` tags are interpreted correctly?

I am using this to send my mail from `functions.php` when the submit button is pressed:

```
   $headers = 'From: XXXXXX.com <info@xxxxx.com>' . "\r\n";
   $subject = 'Registration from xxxxx.com' . "\r\n"; 
   $message = $result_email_text;
   wp_mail($_POST['admin_email'], $subject, $message, $headers );
```

Answer (score 11):

The default content type is `'text/plain'` which does not allow using HTML. You can set the content type of the email by including a header like "Content-type: text/html"

```
$headers = 'Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: XXXXXX.com <info@xxxxx.com>' . "\r\n";
   $subject = 'Registration from xxxxx.com' . "\r\n"; 
   $message = $result_email_text;
   wp_mail($_POST['admin_email'], $subject, $message, $headers );
```

Or you can set it by using the `wp_mail_content_type` filter

```
remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );
function set_html_content_type() {

    return 'text/html';
}
```

For more detail see the following link:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail

Comment: THanks, it's working nice if you are using English. Please, change the charset in your answer to something that is more universal, because unless it's English you would heve problems using iso-8859-1 and it's not recommended anymore to use iso-8859-1. Thanks.

Comment: @Derfder Please accept the answer.so this answer will notify as right and it's useful for the other users.

Comment: Please, add to your answer something like `charset=utf-8` so it is universal, thanks.

Comment: Hi @dipali thanks for your good answer. It worked for me! :-)